# Polymorphic Relations in Laravel naming convenstion

Tags: laravel, polymorphism, polymorphic-associations

I am going to create polymorphic relations in Laravel  but my tables are so old and it's naming conventions are not according to laravel. Can I do this and how ?

Comment: Better add more info about your current database schema.

Comment: Can you add your code?

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can set your table name and FK column names directly.
Look over Realtion [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations) and if necessary in Laravel [API](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_morphToMany) or [source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L975)

If you have

```
posts
    id - integer
    title - string
    body - text

comments
    id - integer
    post_id - integer
    body - text

likes
    id - integer
    likeable_id - integer
    likeable_type - string
```

Then your code will be

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Like extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the owning likeable models.
     */
    public function likeable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo('likeable', 'likeable_type', 'likeable_id');
    }
}

class Post extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the post's likes.
     */
    public function likes()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Like', 'likeable', 'likeable_type', 'likeable_id');
    }
}

class Comment extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the comment's likes.
     */
    public function likes()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Like', 'likeable', 'likeable_type', 'likeable_id');
    }
}
```